# Wrong email href tag link for magento 2.4.2 shipment email

Tags: magento2, email, shipment-tracking

I have followed a below code for adding tracking link to my shipment email.

```
/app/design/frontend/Custom/theme/Magento_Sales/templates/email/shipment/track.phtml

<?php
    $trackurl = '';
    if($_item->getCarrierCode() === 'fedex'){
        $trackurl = 'https://www.fedex.com/apps/fedextrack/?action=track&trackingnumber='.$_item->getNumber();
    }elseif ($_item->getCarrierCode() === 'usps') {
        $trackurl = 'https://tools.usps.com/go/TrackConfirmAction_input?qtc_tLabels1='.$_item->getNumber();
    }elseif ($_item->getCarrierCode() === 'ups') {
        $trackurl = 'https://wwwapps.ups.com/WebTracking/returnToDetails?tracknum='.$_item->getNumber();
    }
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getCarrierCode()) ?>:</td>

         <td style="padding:3px 9px"><a href="<?php echo $trackurl ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getNumber()) ?></a></td>

    </tr>
```

When i click on link then its redirecting me to another random url with suffix 3D.

```
http://url9157.demo.com/ls/click?upn=tbzC-2FQ-2FXJvoNAIfXDjYGpG5qG-2B-2FQgolglhkAgEosZcnLzi7zZuiieXRZ6YYBissP6qclVR9e7Ctdnr0mkCFRpDNJpU8uEjGx3xoe8qQpSd1Lx4qWjasMfEfwapIMZYO0BYvrXa88KBaVekFa2X-2F05U39-2FtTfPCOkEXwbcMwZcar93U4ALrvF58hswnsgXL7LAoWY_kbsIQ9pIaNRQQPhtVzdfT-2BFugGBuGtE5YPB7H9ENlRFNQJlsZlLwnIxHn0RKbjMMiIK4P29nf-2B2KInUjRCggEyWRbHKZyZ3zqjdZeqnIoLTZqn2fVpMk0-2FbyYDBiBk3Kzkm6UTXoUPlqhsWE3ZHKqNpyoinR9c2FNOk32y5LJtxngx1K5-2BP5bE5ZCEaypQpd5pjhNCBOf44lUoFIg5MpNQ-3D-3D
```

$trackurl variable has a correct value but value is changed when its inside href tag.

please help to resolve a issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually an artifact of [SendGrid's universal linking](https://sendgrid.com/docs/ui/sending-email/universal-links/) feature:

> This is accomplished by using universal links. A universal link is a
> unique URL that can be configured to open a window in either the
> recipient's web browser, mobile browser, or mobile application
> depending on the device the recipient is using. SendGrid enables you
> to simply tag individual links that you would like to be converted to
> universal links, without sacrificing the ability to track clicks on
> those links.

SendGrid even gives an example of such a link in their documentation:

> https://links.example.com/wf/click?upn=

Most likely, your site is leveraging either SendGrid or a service like it for tracking and marketing purposes. You'll need to determine what's configured and your options for working around this.